# sys.argv is incomprehensible inside a cython exe

Tags: python, gcc, cython

I made a python exe by using cython --embed and gcc like this

```sh
cython file.pyx ---embed
gcc file.pyx {args} -o file.exe
```

file.pyx contents

```py
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

but when I run the exe it outputs
[b'\xe6\x95\xb4\xe7\x91\xb3']

How do I make it so it returns
["file.py"]

Comment: That is two Japanese characters.  Are you running this on a Japanese system?  And is this Windows?

Comment: This looks like https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3824. You're aren't renaming `main` in your C file? And you are using `-municode`?